# Does vim have the features to be used as an IDE?

Tags: vim, php, javascript, ide

I'm learning vim right now as I use it to quickly fix something in files on a server. Recently I've been thinking of switching from my IDE to vim, but I'm interested if all the features I need are in vim or if they can be added with plugins. I develop mainly in PHP and JavaScript.

What I'm looking for is:

- Contextual help(point on function and see its arguments from oxygen docs)
- Code navigator(list of classes and functions in file to easily move between them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check out http://www.vim.org/scripts for plugins.

Context help is http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=561

Code navigator i don't know right now. But with some google i am sure you find one.
Here is for example python code completion i use: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850

Comment: I found one code navigator: Tag List plugin (http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/installation.html), trying it right now